# Missing dependency when trying to install VirtualBox

Tags: 10.10, package-management, virtualbox, software-center, virtualization

I wanted to install virtualbox-4.0 (or any other version)

- I went to *System → Administration → Synaptic Package Manager*
- Then I marked virtualbox-4.0 for installation but i get this error:

  ```
  virtualbox-4.0:
    Depends: libqt4-opengl but it is not going to be installed
  ```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind installing the Ubuntu version of VirtualBox 3.2 instead of the latest 4.0, install `virtualbox-ose` (VirtualBox Open Source Edition) instead of virtualbox-4.0. `virtualbox-4.0` isn't in the default repositories, you've possibly added a 3rd party repository which isn't compatible with the standard ones. If you cannot wait and *really* want the 4.0 version of VirtualBox, follow the instructions at http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/install-virtualbox-40-stable-in-ubuntu.html.

To install the virtualbox-ose from Ubuntu, you need to remove virtualbox.org from your repositories. Run the next command to remove all lines containing "virtualbox":

```
sudo sed '/virtualbox/d' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Alternatively, remove the three "virtualbox" lines from your /etc/sources.list manually using a text-editor like gedit:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Related launchpad question: [virtualbox-ose 4.0 needs packaging](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-ose/+question/139528)

---

`virtualbox-ose` in ubuntu 11.04 Natty and newer comes with version VirtualBox 4, no additional repositories are necessary.

Comment: I just get the same error even when installing OSE.

Comment: Can you post the output of `find /etc/apt/ -name '*.list' -ls -exec cat {} \;` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add the link to your question?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/560244/

Comment: You need to remove the unofficial VirtualBox repositories from your sources.list. See the updated answer.